# Why doesn't OnKeyDown catch key events in a dialog-based MFC project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, keydown, dialogbasedapp

I just create a dialog-based project in MFC (VS2008) and add `OnKeyDown` event to the dialog.
When I run the project and press the keys on the keyboard, nothing happens. But, if I remove all the controls from the dialog and rerun the project it works.
What should I do to get key events even when I have controls on the dialog?

Here's a piece of code:

```
void CgDlg::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    AfxMessageBox(L"Key down!");
    CDialog::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When a dialog has controls on it, the dialog itself never gets the focus. It's stolen by the child controls. When you press a button, a `WM_KEYDOWN` message is sent to the control with focus so your `CgDlg::OnKeyDown` is never called. Override the dialog's `PreTranslateMessage` function if you want dialog to handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` message:

```
BOOL CgDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
   if(pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN   )  
   {
      if(pMsg->wParam == VK_DOWN)
      {
         ...
      }
      else if(pMsg->wParam == ...)
      {
         ...                      
      }
      ...
      else
      {
         ...                   
      }
   }

   return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);  
}
```

Also see this article on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/pretransdialog01.aspx

Comment: I added a `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` in a dialog, and its `OnKeyDown` method is not being called..

Answer (score 0):

Many of my CDialog apps use OnKeyDown().  As long you only want to receive key presses and draw on the screen (as in make a game), delete the default buttons and static text (the CDialog must be empty) and OnKeyDown() will start working.  Once controls are placed on the CDialog, OnKeyDown() will no longer be called.