# something like jquery .on() in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

i want some code like .on() or.live() jquery function of course in visual studio and c++. the function should work when the user pressed down or up key.

it is a MFC project on visual studio. what i have to do? thanks.

here is the whole code :

```
// MFCApplication5Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication5.h"
#include "MFCApplication5Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication5Dlg dialog



CMFCApplication5Dlg::CMFCApplication5Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication5Dlg::IDD, pParent)
    , oneo(0)
    , twoo(0)
    , threeo(0)
    , fouro(0)
    , fiveo(0)
    , sixo(0)
    , seveno(0)
    , eighto(0)
    , nineo(0)
    //, listo(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, oneo);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, twoo);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT3, threeo);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT4, fouro);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT5, fiveo);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT6, sixo);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT7, seveno);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT8, eighto);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT9, nineo);
    //DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT10, listo);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication5Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
    ON_WM_KEYDOWN()
    ON_WM_KEYDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication5Dlg message handlers

BOOL CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void DD() {

        MessageBoxA(NULL, "hgh", "Result", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    //listo = listo + msg;

    //return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    UpdateData(true);

    int randNum;
    int myarray[9];

    bool find;
    int index = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i <9; i++){
        find = false;
        randNum = rand() % 9 + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (randNum == myarray[j]) {
                find = true;
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!find) {
            myarray[index] = randNum;
            //CString msg;
            //msg.Format(_T("index : %d -> random number is : %d \r\n"), index, randNum);
            //listo = listo + msg;
            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                oneo = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 1:
                twoo = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 2:
                threeo = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 3:
                fouro = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 4:
                fiveo = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 5:
                sixo = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 6:
                seveno = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 7:
                eighto = myarray[index];
                break;
            case 8:
                nineo = myarray[index];
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }




    UpdateData(false);
}


void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    DD();
    CDialogEx::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

here is the image :
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4zNA.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The basic mechanism is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6tw900t.aspx), for instance, you can implement this method for any MFC CWnd objects for handing key down events:

[CWnd::OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/983st27a.aspx)

The general mechanism for event handling in MFC is message maps, details here: [MFC Message Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx).

For instance, you can add handlers by adding the event (e.g. WM_KEYDOWN) using the [event handler wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23w347xy.aspx)

Comment: can i want to explain how to use CWnd::OnKeyDown? i Create a handler using messages, and VS create a function like this `void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
 // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
 CDialogEx::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
`
". ok now what i have to do?

Comment: As per the code generated for you, replace the commented "TODO" line with whatever operation you want performed on the WM_KEYDOWN event.  You can review the MFC samples on the MSDN website for sample code.

Comment: two question : 1-there is no definition which key pressed, then run the function, 2-with this codes nothing happen. when i press down key or every other keys, nothing happen.

Comment: For CDialog-based applications, handling KeyDown is a bit different.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699148/why-doesnt-onkeydown-catch-key-events-in-a-dialog-based-mfc-project for details (OnKeyDown will work fine for traditional MFC apps)